# cc.textureCache.addImage blocking UI

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-js

I want to cache lot of textures in a running scene without blocking it, theoretically cc.textureCache.addImage do caching async if you call it the three arguments. This is not happening.

Code:

```
rainOfArrows: {
_animFrames:[],
loaded: function(){
  console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>LOAD!')
},
load: function(){
  /* Load all animation arrow sprites in memory & generate animation */
  var str = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    str = 'arrow00' + (i < 10 ? ('0' + i) : i) + '.png';
    cc.textureCache.addImage('res/SkilllsAnimations/arrowRain/'+str, this.loaded, this);
    var spriteFrame = new cc.SpriteFrame(texture, cc.rect(0,0,winsize.width,winsize.height));

    cc.spriteFrameCache.addSpriteFrame(spriteFrame, str);
    this._animFrames.push(cc.spriteFrameCache.getSpriteFrame(str));
  }
},
run: function():{ ----- }
}
```

The function loaded is executed and string '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>LOAD!' is printed async. But the hole scene freezes until all textures are loaded.

Before v3.0, this was done with addImageAsync and worked fine, now in 3.2 this is merged in addImage but I can not get it working, am I missing something?

Btw, i'm not using textures packed in one img and plist because they're too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix for this has been submitted by pandamicro and will be available in 3.4

Here it is in case you need it before 3.4: https://github.com/pandamicro/cocos2d-js/commit/2a124b5